# App Store internal distribution fails to add my organization ID

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

It fails with the error "The Organization ID or Apple ID you entered could not be found. Try again."

I've input my own Organization ID which has been approved, and it fails every time with this error. I initially thought it might need some time for the. new organization ID to propagate, but it has been over 24hrs now and I still get the same error.

Comment: same here: I've filled feedback,  FB9633130

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out! The issue was the Organization Name field, which happened to be the same as the name of the the organization my app store connect account it associated with. By just changing the string in that field (I added " Inc" at the end), it worked!

Comment: in our case we had an extra comma

Comment: Brutal, I feel your pain @OlegKovtun

Answer (score 0):

In our case, the problem was also in the Organization name (although the error message shows the Organization ID), which had to match  *exactly* (including periods and separators) the Organization name in Apple Business Manager.